# Google plus interactive post recipients not working

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I've got a list of IDs by requesting the google+ friends of a logged in user. I've tried to set those IDs in the recipients field. I've also tried setting valid emails in there. Nothing gets pre-populated in the dialog box. Here's my code below:

```
var options = {
   contenturl: 'google.com',
   clientid: 'MyClientId',
   cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
   prefilltext: 'Create your Google+ Page too!',
   recipients: 'some_email@gmail.com',
   calltoactionlabel: 'JOIN_ME',
   calltoactionurl: 'google.com'
};
gapi.interactivepost.render('button', options);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known bug

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1125